# SAP HYBRIS [Y] : How to create our custom widget in backoffice

Tags: widget, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice, zul

I am a beginner in the Sap Hybris. I want to understand the backoffice extension 
and how to create our custom widget. Just a small example to understand with the different steps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to clear the steps to create a widget

**Creating a Widget**

To create a widget, you need to start by creating a widget definition. The definition of a widget is provided in `definition.xml` file.

**Procedure**

1. In `myextension/backoffice/resources/widgets` directory create a new folder called mysearch.
2. In the mysearch folder, create a definition.xml file.
3. Add information about the search widget.

You can provide information like name, description, default title, author, and version. Each widget must have a unique ID made up of the extension and widget names. For this tutorial, the widget ID is org.myextension.widgets.mysearch.

***definition.xml :***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<widget-definition id="org.myextension.widgets.mysearch" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.hybris.com/schema/cockpitng/widget-definition.xsd">

    <name>My Search</name>
    <description>My own search widget.</description>
    <defaultTitle>Search</defaultTitle>
    <author>Me</author>
    <version>0.1</version>

</widget-definition>
```

**Creating a Widget View :**

The view of this widget is defined in a ZK ZUL file, named after the last part of the widget ID as specified in the definition.xml (in this case mysearch.zul).

**Context**

In the mysearch.zul file, you define all frontend components. For the search widget, you need two components: a text box and a button.

**Procedure**

1. In the mysearch folder, create the mysearch.zul file.
2. Add the text box and button components, providing an ID for each, along with a button label.
   Your mysearch.zul file should look more or less like the following example.

**mysearch.zul**

```xml
<widget xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul">
    <style src="${wr}/default.css"/>
    <div>
        <hlayout>
            <textbox id="searchInput"/>
            <button id="searchBtn" label="Search"/>
        </hlayout>
    </div>
</widget>
```

**Deploying the Widget**

Now, the newly created widget needs to get deployed.

**Procedure**

1. Include your new extension:

   a. Open the <HYBRIS_CONFIG_DIR>/localextensions.xml file.

   b. Add the following line
   `<extension name="myextension" />`

   c. Save the file.
2. Build your project:

Call ant clean all to build SAP Hybris Commerce and start server

**Adding the Widget to an Application**

After deploying a widget, you need to add the widget to an application.

**Implementing the Search Service**

The widget requires implementing some logic. As the widget is responsible for search, the SearchService is to be implemented.

**Context**

Before creating controller, you must add a SearchService, which is used by your search widget.

**Procedure**

1. Add a new class named SearchService to the src folder within the org.myextension package. The following code is an example implementation.

**SearchService.java**

```java
package org.myextension;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SearchService {
    public List<String> search(final String text) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        result.add(text);
        result.add("Hello");
        result.add("Cockpit NG");
        result.add("Developer");

        return result;
    }
}
```

2. Add the new implementation to the Spring context file located in myextension/resources directory:

**myextension-backoffice-spring.xml**

```xml
<bean id="searchService" class="org.myextension.SearchService"/>
```

**Creating a Controller**

The newly created widget requires a widget controller.

**Context**

As you have not defined any action for the Search button, nothing happens if it is clicked. For this you need to create a controller.

**Procedure**

1. In myextension/backoffice/src/org/myextension, create a controller with the following package name:
   org.myextension.widgets.mysearch.

The controller should extend DefaultWidgetController. Name it MySearchController.

2. Add the implementation for the following actions:

   a. When a search query is typed in the text box, it should trigger the search.

   b. When the Search button is pressed, the search for the search query should be executed.

**MySearchController.java**

```java
package org.myextension.widgets.mysearch;

import java.util.List;

import org.myextension.SearchService;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Events;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.annotation.WireVariable;
import org.zkoss.zul.Messagebox;
import org.zkoss.zul.Textbox;

import com.hybris.cockpitng.annotations.ViewEvent;
import com.hybris.cockpitng.util.DefaultWidgetController;

public class MySearchController extends DefaultWidgetController {
    private Textbox searchInput;

    @WireVariable
    private SearchService searchService;

    @ViewEvent(componentID = "searchBtn", eventName = Events.ON_CLICK)
    public void doSearch() throws InterruptedException {
        List<String> result = searchService.search(searchInput.getText());
        Messagebox.show(result.get(0));
    }
}
```

3. Add a controller class in definition.xml (the one located in myextension/backoffice/resources/widgets/mysearch directory).

**definition.xml**

4. Rebuild the system like you did in the Deploying the Widget procedure.
5. Click the Search button.

A pop-up message appears with the same text that you typed into the text box.

Comment: Tx for the steps, but where is the mysearch.zul file ?

Answer (score 0):

have to create mysearch.zul as well

```xml
<widget xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul">
    <style src="${wr}/default.css"/>
    <div>
        <hlayout>
            <textbox id="searchInput"/>
            <button id="searchBtn" label="Search"/>
        </hlayout>
    </div>
</widget>
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks